# typesetting system

Tags: linux, latex

All my life I used Microsoft Office on Windows for document writing and then Libre(Open)Office on Linux. This is not a bad software, but not perfect and I have some complaints. Now on my usual desktop I have Linux.

I heard from people who work a lot with documents of different type and complexity (diagrams, articles, document design, presentation) that LaTeX is a perfect thing. I have spent two days exploring Latex and my opinion as a beginner that it is out-of-date (the concepts of LaTeX language). The language is not intuitive and sometimes even complex.

Can somebody advise another software product for document writing?

Comment: I'm curious as to what concepts specifically you consider out of date. It's certainly a complex language (most useful programming languages are), but that's necessary for it to be as powerful as it is (just like PostScript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX is pretty much the most used tool for professional typesetting in Linux, even though it is complex. While it's not perfect, it is much better for that purpose than Office-type packages are.

However, [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) might be useful as a desktop publishing tool.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has [InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign.html) which provides sophisticated typography and layout features with a WYSIWYG interface. It is not free but you can download a full featured, time limited trial version to help you decide whether it is suitable for your needs.

Comment: InDeSign doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: Ah, I missed the Linux tag.

Answer (score 1):

If LaTeX is too complex for you (why?) there's markdown: I suggest [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). It can use LaTeX under the hood. `:-)`

Comment: Are you serious ? pandoc is an useful tool, but not a substitute for Latex.

Answer (score 1):

there is [LOUT](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lout/). works on non-linux as well.